# Jsf Column not resizing when on seperate Tab

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a TabView with two tabs as shown in the code below. My problem is that only the first dataTable has resizable columns although I have set it on both dataTables whose ids are comments and achivedComments. If I move the dataTables around only the first one has the the columns resizing. When I check the source using viewSource on the browser I notice that  is only on the first dataTable not the second. If I put both dataTables on the same tab I also notice that both dataTables have resizable columns i.e they work properly.

```
<p:dialog closable="true" dynamic="true" header="#{msg['00156']}"
    widgetVar="viewCommentsDlg" width="800" modal="true" showEffect="drop"
    hideEffect="drop">
    <h:form id="viewCommentsForm">
        <p:growl showDetail="true" life="2500" />
        <p:tabView>
            <p:contextMenu for="comments">
                <p:menuitem actionListener="#{comment.deleteComment}"
                    value="#{msg['00232']}"
                    update=":viewCommentsForm :ietpViewMenuBarForm:ietpViewMenuBar"
                    icon="ui-icon-trash" global="false"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
            <p:tab title="#{msg['01094']}"
                disabled="#{!comment.commentsAvailable}">
                <p:dataTable scrollable="true" scrollHeight="340"
                    rowKey="#{c.messageID}" value="#{comment.commentList}" var="c"
                    resizableColumns="true" selection="#{comment.selectedComment}"
                    selectionMode="single" sortBy="#{c.messageID}" id="comments">

                    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" global="false"/>

                    <p:column style="width: 20px">
                        <p:rowToggler />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['00152']}" sortBy="#{c.messageID}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.messageID}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['00626']}" sortBy="#{c.originator}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.originator}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:rowExpansion>
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.message}" />
                    </p:rowExpansion>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="#{msg['01096']}"
                disabled="#{comment.viewArchiveCommentDisabled}">
                <p:dataTable scrollable="true" scrollHeight="340"
                    rowKey="#{ac.messageID}" value="#{comment.archivedCommentList}"
                    var="ac" resizableColumns="true" selection="#{comment.selectedComment}"
                    selectionMode="single" sortBy="#{ac.messageID}"
                    id="archivedComments">

                    <p:column style="width: 20px">
                        <p:rowToggler />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['00152']}" sortBy="#{ac.messageID}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ac.messageID}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['00626']}" sortBy="#{ac.originator}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ac.originator}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:rowExpansion>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ac.message}" />
                    </p:rowExpansion>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>

        <p:commandButton onclick="viewCommentsDlg.hide();"
            style="float: righ`enter code here`t; margin-top: 10px; width: 80px; margin-bottom: 10px"
            type="button" value="#{msg['00138']}" />

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `disabled` attribute from p:tab then check both tables

Comment: I have tried to remove the disable attribute from both tabs but no luck